# run my executable under Linux

Tags: linux, windows, dll

I have coded an executable(based on mpi libraries) under visual 2012(windows8.1). This exe needs other dlls. I want to make this executable working under Linux machine. What is the best solution?

thanks

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29

Comment: Yes I did run it with wine But I encoutred other problems because my executable depends on dlls that I have compiled under windows.